# how to proguard with intellij idea gradle intellij-plugin

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, proguard, intellij-plugin

how to proguard with intellij idea gradle intellij-plugin?

use the code can not work for me !

config build.gradle

```
def ideaPath = "D:/java/ideaIU-2022.1.3.win"
task proguard(type: ProGuardTask) {
//    dependsOn intelli

    verbose

//    injars  "${buildDir}/libs/xxx-1.4.8.jar"
    injars  "${buildDir}/classes/java/main"
    outjars "${buildDir}/libs/xxx-1.4.8-obfuscatedClasses.jar"

    // Automatically handle the Java version of this build.
    if (System.getProperty('java.version').startsWith('1.')) {
        // Before Java 9, the runtime classes were packaged in a single jar file.
        libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/rt.jar"
    } else {
        // As of Java 9, the runtime classes are packaged in modular jmod files.
        libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/jmods/java.base.jmod", jarfilter: '!**.jar', filter: '!module-info.class'
        libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/jmods/java.sql.jmod",    jarfilter: '!**.jar', filter: '!module-info.class'
        libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/jmods/java.desktop.jmod", jarfilter: '!**.jar', filter: '!module-info.class'

        //libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/jmods/....."
    }

    // This will contain the Spring dependencies.
    libraryjars sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
//    libraryjars fileTree("$ideaPath/plugins/java/lib").filter { !it.name.startsWith("debugger") }.collect()
//    libraryjars files("$ideaPath/lib")

    dontnote 'kotlin.**'
    dontnote 'kotlinx.**'
    dontnote 'org.intellij.**'
    dontnote 'com.intellij.**'
    dontnote 'com.google.gson.**'
    dontnote 'proguard.configuration.ConfigurationLogger'

    dontobfuscate

    optimizationpasses 10

    keepclasseswithmembers 'public class * {  \
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]); \
    }'

    // Keep the main class entry point.
    keep 'public class com.example.demo.DemoApplication { \
            public static void main(java.lang.String[]); \
         }'

    keepattributes '*Annotation*'

    // This simple example requires classes with @Component annotation classes
    // to be kept, since otherwise components could end up with clashing names,
    // if they do not set the name explicitly.
    keep 'public @org.springframework.stereotype.Component class *'

    // You may need to keep classes or members based on other annotations such as:
    keepclassmembers 'public class * { \
            @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired *; \
            @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value *; \
        }'

    // After ProGuard has executed, repackage the app.
//    finalizedBy tasks.repackage
}
```

Are there any examples that can be executed?
My idea Version: ideaIU-2022.1.3.win
Java Version:

- openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment JBR-11.0.15.10-2043.56-jcef (build 11.0.15+10-b2043.56)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM JBR-11.0.15.10-2043.56-jcef (build 11.0.15+10-b2043.56, mixed mode)

Gralde Version: gradle-7.5.1

the error message:

```
2022-08-10T11:20:00.704+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2022-08-10T11:20:00.704+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2022-08-10T11:20:00.704+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2022-08-10T11:20:00.704+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2022-08-10T11:20:00.704+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':proguard'.
2022-08-10T11:20:00.704+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
2022-08-10T11:20:00.704+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2022-08-10T11:20:00.704+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2022-08-10T11:20:00.704+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
2022-08-10T11:20:00.704+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
2022-08-10T11:20:00.704+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2022-08-10T11:20:00.704+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
2022-08-10T11:20:00.704+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
2022-08-10T11:20:00.704+0800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 10s
11:20:00: 'proguard --debug'。
```

Thks！

Comment: *can not work for me* can you please tell us what is the specific error you encountered?

Comment: Check this: https://www.picimako.com/obfuscating-plugins-with-proguard/